# Why the following python code of constructor give me and error?

Tags: python

```
class Student:
    college = 'usa'
    name = 'rahul'

    #error message ?
    def __init__(self):
        print('new Student is entered ...')
    
    #para cons
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

a = Student()
```

Please check what mistake i did in above code

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Python does not allow function overloading: in your example, you define two different versions of `__init__()`. Try consolidating the functionality of each into one definition, perhaps like:

```py
class Student:
    college = 'usa'

    def __init__(self, name='rahul'):

        self.name = name

        if self.name is not 'rahul':
            print('new Student is entered ...')

a = Student()
```

Comment: Better yet, make `name` required and let `Student()` raise an exception instead of printing an error message that can be ignored.

Comment: Better use something like `name=None` so that rahul isn't sad that it is so hard for him to enroll in college.

Answer (score 1):

It gave you an error because your second constructor *overrode* the first. Then, when you tried to construct an instance without the required parameter, it rightly complained.

Python does *not* have method overloading based on parameter count or types, such as you find in C++.

That's because the method names are simply keys in a `__dict__` for the class, and dictionary keys must be unique.

Python provides *emulation* of function overloading by using default parameter values, so you could do something like this:

```py
class Student:
    DEFAULT_NAME = 'rahul'

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name is None:
            print(f"New Student, assuming {Student.DEFAULT_NAME}")
            self.name = Student.DEFAULT_NAME
        else:
            self.name = name

a = Student()
print(a.name)  # Outputs: rahul

b = Student("Bob")
print(b.name)  # Outputs: Bob
```

It basically depends on the behaviour expected from the two cases.

I should mention that a default name of `rahul` seems rather strange unless you live in a country where the *vast* majority of people have that name, and the default country of USA is probably *not* one of those :-)

A better approach would be, I believe, to *not* default the name, though I realise this may simply be a small, not necessarily exact, example for the purposes of the question.

---

As an aside, you may wonder why I didn't just provide `'rahul'` rather than `None` as the default. Two reasons really:

- You seemed to want a message printed when no name was given so you need to be able to distinguish between `None` and someone explicitly providing `"rahul"`.
- It's better to provide `None` as the default to be explicit in what was done. This is doubly important when providing a type that is mutable (like `[]`). The default is created once at *definition* time so, if it changes, the next call will use the *changed* value.

On that final bullet point, see this code for example:

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, names=[]):
        self.names = names
        self.names.append("Bob")

a = Student()
print(a.names)  # Outputs: ["Bob"]

b = Student()
print(b.names)  # Outputs: ["Bob", "Bob"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you have two `__init__` methods in your Student class. In Python, you can't have two methods with the same name in the same class. The second one will override the first one.

In your case, the `__init__` method that takes a name parameter is overriding the `__init__` method that takes no parameters. So when you try to create a Student object with no parameters, Python can't find a matching `__init__` method and raises a TypeError.

Here's how you can fix your code:

```
class Student:
    college = 'usa'
    name = 'rahul'

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name is not None:
            self.name = name
        print('new Student is entered ...')

a = Student()
```

In this code, the `__init__` method takes an optional name parameter. If a name is provided when creating a Student object, it sets self.name to the provided name. Otherwise, it leaves self.name as 'rahul'.

Answer (score 1):

1. Python will consider only second constructor.
2. Your second constructor is having parameter, so pass parameter value while creating object of class

   class Student:

   #error message ?
   def **init**(self):
   print('new Student is entered ...')

   #para cons
   def **init**(self, name):
   self.name = name
   print("seceond construtor",name)

a = Student('rahul')

Try this !!

Answer (score 0):

A student (presumably) needs a name. If no name is provided, that should raise an exception, not allow you to proceed with an improperly initialized instance of `Student`.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

a = Student()  # Raises a TypeError
b = Student("rahul")  # Registers Rahul
```